# Is it possible to write UI testing on Xcode that tests facebook log in?

Tags: xcode, facebook, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I want to write a UI test that covers facebook login on the app.
I am struggling to think of way automating this on xcode.
Is using SSafariViewController the answer?

Comment: show your code how you tried to do this

Comment: I havent written any code for this part, wondering if it is possible?

Comment: if you can login to facebook through your ios app manually, you can also do it using xcode ui test. first create a ui tescase class in ui test folder than record your scenario and run. lots of resource you will found about this on google. here one is video link: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiFhoSJ7_DOAhXCpI8KHZA_B_gQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fvideos%2Fplay%2Fwwdc2015%2F406%2F&usg=AFQjCNFc0VX7MtljkKsNWNf4kIZBPdfQ3g&sig2=tl8VmLc33JVyG6cw9jqWiA

Comment: @noor Hmm, I have investigated the video and cannot see any documentation what would enable a facebook log in via XCT testing. I believe the interface can only react with the app and only the app. No external applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, you can only interact with the app you have created no external software.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by creating a reference to the WebView where the Facebook Login appears, something like this (where the variable app is the XCUIApplication reference initiated on setUp)

```
XCUIElement *facebookDialog = (XCUIElement *) [app descendantsMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeWebView];
XCUIElement *emailTextField = (XCUIElement *) facebookDialog.textFields[@"Email or Phone"];
XCUIElement *passwordTextField = facebookDialog.secureTextFields[@"Facebook Password"];
[emailTextField tap];
[emailTextField typeText:emailString];
[passwordTextField tap];
[passwordTextField typeText:passwordString];

[facebookDialog.buttons[@"Log In"] tap];
[facebookDialog.buttons[@"OK"] tap];
```